# Effect on variance when 2 observations out of the set of n observations are added and subtracted with a constant

Tags: statistics, variance, standard-deviation, means

Set $y$ is given such that,

$$y= (y_1,y_2,...,y_n)$$
And 
$$y_1\leq y_2\leq...\leq y_n$$

Now take $y'$ such that
$$y'= (y_1,\ y_2,...,\  y_j+c,\ y_{j
+1},....,\ y_k-c,\ y_{k
+1}...,y_n)$$

Essentially subtracted a constant from some $y_j$ term and added the same constant constant to larger $y_k$ term.
And it is given that even after doing this, 
$$y_j+c< y_{j+1} <...< y_{k-1}< y_k-c$$

What will be the relation between the variance of the set $y$ and $y'$? Answer is that the variance will reduce after the operation.

I have tried doing the problem by comparing the terms that change in the variance. This is because the mean remains same for both the set. But all efforts in vain since I am not getting anywhere. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to compare the terms that change in the variance is exactly right.

Subtracting the old terms from the new terms yields (a multiple of)

$$
(y_j+c)^2+(y_k-c)^2-y_j^2-y_k^2=2c(y_j-y_k+c)\;.
$$

It is given that $y_j+c\lt y_k-c$ and thus $y_j-y_k+c\lt -c$. You didn't state that $c$ is positive, but we need to assume that it is to conclude that the difference is negative and thus the variance is reduced. (The active form is “decreases”, not “reduces”.)

Comment: Why would you simply subtract these terms ? For the variance the observations are subtracted by the mean of the set. The mean of both the sets will be same,say some $\nu$.

Comment: @DivyeshShah: $\mathsf{Var}[X]=\mathsf E\left[X^2\right]-\mathsf E[X]^2$. So if $\mathsf E[X]$ is invariant, we just have to compare $\mathsf E\left[X^2\right]$.

Comment: The terms in variance will not be what you have written, I believe. Once will have to subtract the mean as well from these observations before squaring them. And I am getting a very different answer once I do that. Hence I am stuck. The mean will be equal for both sets here, lets say some $\nu$ \ $$
(y_j+c-\nu)^2+(y_k-c-\nu)^2-(y_j-\nu)^2-(y_k-\nu)^2;.
$$

Comment: @DivyeshShah: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Are you disagreeing with $\mathsf{Var}[X]=\mathsf E\left[X^2\right]-\mathsf E[X]^2$? If so, please see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition).

Comment: But shouldn't we get the same answer whether we consider the mean or not ? I don't seem to get it.

Comment: Those are two different arguments. You were saying that my answer was wrong. If we agree that my answer is right, we can proceed to check why you're not getting the same result with your approach including the means.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your approach hence I am trying to compare my approach by taking the answer to your approach as the benchmark.I am taking the set definition of variance which is $$Var[X}=E[(X- \nu)^2]$$

Comment: You haven't written out your calculation. When I do  the calculation that way, I get the correct result, too, so if you want to find out what you did wrong, you need to write out what you did.

Comment: Let me write it down here. Sorry my Mathjax is very slow$$
(y_j+c-\nu)^2+(y_k-c-\nu)^2-(y_j-\nu)^2-(y_k-\nu)^2;.
$$ \ \ $$ (y_j - \nu)^2 + c^2 +2c(y_j - \nu) + (y_k- \nu)^2 +c^2 - 2c(y_k - \nu) - (y_j - \nu)^2 - (y_k- \nu)^2$$ This give me $$2c^2 +2c(y_j-y_k)$$ Which has ambiguous sign as $$(y_j-y_k) \ \ is \ \ -ve $$

Comment: Again, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. This is exactly the difference that I got in my answer (just that you didn't factor out $2c$). I showed in the answer that this difference is negative. In any event, there's no discrepancy here between the approaches with or without the means.

Comment: I think I get it now, @joriki. I was misunderstanding the last step manipulations. Thank you very much for enduring my slow understanding.